# Website content scrolling over a fading header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

Trying to do this on my website; content scrolling over header while header image is fading out (of course I want the header image to show up again while returning at the top of the page). I've managed to do this with Javascript;

```
<script>
var divs = $('.head');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 20) {
        divs.stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        divs.stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");
    }
});         
</script>
```

This script just makes my image to go away with one single scroll - I'd like to have at least 3 different opacity levels before my image fades away completely. And at the same time content scrolls over the image (image position: fixed). Can I do this with this script? Or should I use some CSS -trick (with opacity) to do this?

--

Okay, so here are we now (Thanks to Capricorn!):

```
        <script>
            var div = $('.head');
            $(window).scroll(function(){
               if($(window).scrollTop()>10) {
                     div.stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 0.75);
               } if($(window).scrollTop()>150){
                     div.stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 0.4);
               } if($(window).scrollTop()>200){
                 div.stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 0);
               }
            });
        </script>
```

I've managed to fade my header image with 3 scrolls. But got three new problems.. My image keeps flashing (from opacity 0.4 to 0) while scrolling beneath 200px, and I cannot figure out how I'm supposed to add this to my script (yep, new with Java). And also, when I scroll back to top, my image stays at opacity 0.75 (want it back with no opacity = 1).

And in addition, is the problem with CSS or Javascript that when I scroll, the content doesn't replace the header image, and they're there at the same time. It's like with this script it changes 's opacity, and only with fadeTo("slow", 0); -option my content is shown perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the duration in numbers.

```
fadeOut(2000)
```

[API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with your current script.

Add two more if branches for different scrolling positions, eg *scrollTop() < 50* and *scrollTop() < 80* and instead of fading in or out the header completely use [jQuery's fadeTo function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

Comment: Thanks a alot! I'm kind of new with Javascript, so could you help me with my couple of new problems (edited the original post)?